# Make watch reevaluate command

Tags: watch

Hi I have a problem running watch command like this:

```
 watch cat /proc/$(ps ax | grep processname | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')/status
```

The command works when I start it. However, then I restart the process being watched and the watch command still uses old process id. I want it to refresh the process id and show the status of a new process with the same name. The part `$(ps ax | grep processname | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')` is obviously ran only at the start. How can I make it to be reevaluated every time the watch refreshes the output?

I would not like to put the cat command in a bash script and run that script from watch.

Comment: put it in a script and run the script with watch

Comment: btw, use `pgrep`.  `ps | grep | grep -v | awk` "works"  but there are many better ways - even `ps ax | awk '/processname/ && ! /awk/ {print $1}'` is better.   or `ps -o pid -C processname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a neat way, but if you really feel reluctant to create a script. You can try `eval`.

```
 watch eval 'cat /proc/$(ps ax | grep processname | grep -v grep | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"')/status'
```

Comment: This is a bit misleading.  Since `watch` starts by "helpfully" concatenating all of its args together into a single command string, your command is actually exactly equivalent to: `watch 'eval cat /proc/$(ps ax | grep processname | grep -v grep | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"')/status'` .  From that, it's evident that the `eval` isn't serving any purpose, so you can just leave it out: `watch 'cat /proc/$(ps ax | grep processname | grep -v grep | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"')/status'`  which is the same as the final command in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following as, e.g. `ps-status.sh` somewhere in your $PATH and make it executable with `chmod +x`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

[ -z "$1" ] && echo "process name required" && exit 1

pid="$(pgrep -f "$1")"

[ -z "$pid" ] && echo "no such process: $1" && exit 1

countpids="$(echo "$pid" | wc -l)"
[ "$countpids" -gt 1 ] && "Warning: more than one pid matches $1" && exit 1


cat "/proc/$pid/status"
```

Then run `watch` like so:

```
watch ps-status.sh processname
```

`$pid` should probably be an array, but that would require bash rather than just sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && echo "process name required" && exit 1

pids=( $(pgrep -f "$1") )

[ "${#pids[@]}" -eq 0 ] && echo "no such process: $1" && exit 1
[ "${#pids[@]}" -gt 1 ] && echo "Warning: more than one pid matches $1"

# display first matching PID, even if there were more than 1 matching.
cat "/proc/${#pids[0]}/status"
```

Answer (score 1):

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -eaf | grep -i processname| grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'
/etc/init.d/servicename restart
```

---

explaination

schedule the crontab  for every 1 minutes

Then use the below watch command to see the difference in process id after restarting the process name

```
watch -n 60 script.sh
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can just single-quote the `$(...)` to prevent its expansion by the interactive shell you're running the thing from from.  And then you have to escape the single-quotes that you have inside that, by temporarily switching to double-quotes and back.  So the following works:

```
watch cat /proc/'$(ps ax | grep processname | grep -v grep | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"')'/status
```

However, in order to understand what `watch` is doing, here and in general, you have to keep in mind that `watch` starts by joining together all its non-flag args into a single command string.  It does that in order to be "helpful", but I think it's actually counterproductive since it obscures what's going on.  I think it's cleaner and easier to understand if you always give it just a single command string, in this case single-quoted to prevent your interactive shell from expanding anything in it:

```
watch 'cat /proc/$(ps ax | grep processname | grep -v grep | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"')/status'
```